# Facebook SDK didLoad:result = null

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook singleton and request this to get a profile picture:

```
[[[FacebookScorer sharedInstance] facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture?type=normal" andDelegate:self];
```

Now in facebooks delegate method didLoadRawResponce I actually receive the profile picture and can display, but in the didLoad:(id)result method the result is null!

I believe the didLoad method is called once the result has been parsed, so why do I not get anything back from it?

The reason I need to use didLoad, is I can ask it if the result isKindOfClass to see what it is, whereas didLoadRawResponce is also called when I logout, so how can I check what the data is?

--Edit
I have figured out how to differentiate between FBRequests, so this isn't such a great problem anymore, however I still can't understand why didLoad is being called but without any result.
Even using this gives triggers the slog, but with null

```
if (request == _profilePicRequest) {
    NSLog(@"result:%@",result);
}
```

Comment: did you try to implement `- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;` and to check if there is some error happened ?

Comment: Yes, there is no error. didLoad is being called, result is null though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by getting the data from the request:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result{
result = request.responseText;

if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
{   
    ...
}

if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    ...
}
```

Not the most elegant solution, and I still don't know why the result is nil. But it works.

Hope this helps!